# Why is merge sort faster at sorting a reverse sorted list than a normal sorted list?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am doing a comparison based analysis of mergesort algorithm which outputs in ascending order.  I notice it is faster (has fewer comparisons) when I give it a reverse sorted list instead of an ascending order sorted list.  Can anybody explain why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/758280

Comment: @Jeffrey I assume that he is counting the number of comparisons (he writes "less comparisons"), which should rule out branch prediction.

Comment: I actually just had this same occurrence, where the number of comparisons is exactly the length of the array when on a reversed array. The number of comparisons on random and sorted arrays follows the n(log(n)) pattern.

Answer (score 3):

To merge two lists of length M and N you need at most M+N-1 comparisons. If all the entries in the first list are smaller than the ones in the second list, you only need M comparisons. If all the entries in the second list are smaller then the ones in the first list, you only need N comparisons.

If the total amount of numbers you are sorting isn't a potency of 2, you will have cases where you divide into two lists of different length. I suspect you implemented merge-sort in a way that the first of those two has one element more. That means M = N+1 for that partition and merging. If your elements are in reverse order, all the elements of the second list will be smaller than the ones of your first list and you will need N comparisons instead of M in the case of correct order.

If the list you want to sort is a potency of 2, there should be no difference between normal order and reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an error in your sorting code.

From my understanding, the number of comparisons executed by literal MergeSort should be *independent* of the data. Which means it cannot be worse than `O(n log n)`, but also not better (unless you do some smart modifications, like in "natural mergesort" or TimSort).

Comment: *From my understanding, the number of comparisons executed by literal MergeSort should be independent of the data.* I'm afraid you are mistaken, as explained in Judith's answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a top-down mergesort implementation, an ascending order sorted list does not go through the merge() step in the code below. Therefore, it is the fastest. Also, a reverse sorted list skips some portion of comparison steps inside the merge() step. For example, it does not go into the comparison line below in my code.

```
else if (comp(aux[j], aux[i])) a[k] = aux[j++];     // B[j] <  A[i], take B[je
```

Therefore, it is also faster than a randomly ordered list that goes through all the code.

For your reference:

```
void merge(int *a, int *aux, int lo, int mi, int hi, bool (*comp)(int, int)) {
    assert(sorted(a, lo,   mi, comp));      // precondition: a[lo..mi]   sorted
    assert(sorted(a, mi+1, hi, comp));      // precondition: a[mi+1..hi] sorted
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)  aux[k] = a[k];

    int i = lo;
    int j = mi + 1;
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        if (i > mi)       a[k] = aux[j++];     // A is exhausted, take B[j]
        else if (j > hi)  a[k] = aux[i++];     // B is exhausted, take A[i]
        else if (comp(aux[j], aux[i])) a[k] = aux[j++];     // B[j] <  A[i], take B[j]
        else                           a[k] = aux[i++];     // A[i] <= B[j], take A[i]
    }
    assert(sorted(a, lo, hi, comp));        // postcondition: a[lo..hi] sorted
}

void mergesort(int *a, int *aux, int lo, int hi, bool (*comp)(int, int)) {
    if (hi <= lo) return;
    int mi = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    mergesort(a, aux, lo,     mi, comp);
    mergesort(a, aux, mi + 1, hi, comp);
    
    if (comp(a[mi], a[mi + 1])) return;  // already sorted
    merge(a, aux, lo, mi, hi, comp);
}
```

(a debtor)<><